# Can WSO2 IS 5.3.0 server generate SP metadata file ( for SAML2 SSO ) from the configuration

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I have configured the WSO2 IS 5.3.0 server to work with my application as the IDP of SAML2 based SSO system. Can I generate the metadata file from the configuration so that I could reuse it?

Answer (score 0):

IS 5.3.0 doesn't support this option to download SP metadata as a file